# Mapbox GL JS Image Overlay Coordinates Precision Issue

Tags: mapbox

I'm facing a precision issue with Mapbox GL JS when placing an image overlay on the map with 4 corners coordinates, there is a shift from the expected position by 50-250 m. To reach this conclusion and find this bug, the projection of the image was compared to Leaflet and QGIS, both of them shows the same position of the image but Mapbox GL JS is showing a shift.

I think this may be a bug in the framework that needs to be fixed. I'm using React Mapbox GL JS and was able to recreate this issue using Mapbox GL JS library within a normal html file. So most probably it's not being caused by React.

To recreate the issue try to overlay an image on the map using Mapbox, Leaflet and QGIS and then compare the results.

mapbox-gl-js version: 1.4.0

browser: Google Chrome Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Steps to Trigger Behavior
Add an image overlay to Mapbox GL JS using 4 coordinates

```
map.addSource("imageTest", {
"type": "image",
"url": "/DIR/TO/IMAGE",
"coordinates": [
    [LON1,LAT1],
    [LON2,LAT2],
    [LON3,LAT3],
    [LON4,LAT4]
]
})

map.addLayer({
"id": "overlay",
"source": "imageTest",
"type": "raster"
})
```

Geo reference the same image using GDAL Georeferencer on QGIS with the same coordinates and use QGIS to load the resulting GeoTIFF.

Overlay the image using Leaflet Distortable Image https://github.com/publiclab/Leaflet.DistortableImage

Compare the 3 projections, a shift shall be observed only with the Mapbox projection and on the y axis most probably.

Expected Behavior
All of these methods should yield the same results.

Actual Behavior
Mapbox is showing a major shift sometimes up to 250 meters for an image with a swath of 3 km.

Check this screenshot: (QGIS left, Mapbox center, Leaflet right)
[image: QGIS left, Mapbox center, Leaflet right]

Answer (score 2):

The problem does have to do with projection. Images can be sliced and diced exactly by coordinates but they must match the projection of the map they are being overlaid on. In the case of Mapbox, it uses web mercator and images must be reprojected to EPSG:3857.

A utility to convert images (such as geoTIF) to this projection is GDAL (https://gdal.org/). A command using GDAL tools to convert an image would be something like :

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 input.tif input-projected.tif
```

Hopefully this clears things up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer David. I'm trying to project thousands of JPEG images using Mapbox GL JS image overlay, so converting the JPEG's to GTiff's and then warping them into Web Mercator EPSG:3857 won't be efficient for my use case. Do you know how this can be fixed from mapbox gl js side and not from the images side? I believe that the image overlay takes EPSG:4326 lon,lat as input and project them to Web Mercator and then project the images to the map, am I correct?

Comment: @laithalzyoud If I understand your question correctly, there is nothing you can do on the Mapbox side to correct this. It must come in as 3857 or there will be problems.  Mapbox won't warp the images on-the-fly. When I first had the problem, I tried everything until I learned it MUST be done in 3857, sadly. Do you just need to convert the 1000's of images *one* time? If so, a script could do it once for you. You can use imagemagick to help you with GDAL to get pretty much anything you want done. I am curious to see your problem.

Comment: I'm using raw aerial images and I have their four corners coordinates generated by an algorithm in longitude, latitude format. I projected these images using both Leaflet distortable image(https://github.com/publiclab/Leaflet.DistortableImage) and QGIS. Both showed the expected image position and was similar to each other. But when Mapbox GL JS was used there was a shift compared to the previous ones by 50-250 meters. The image overlay in Mapbox takes an image and 4 lon, lat coordinates and does the mercator projection within the library. I think there is an issue in how they use WebGL.

Comment: Check the screenshot that I added showing how the images is shifted to have a better understanding of the situation.